# How to model different variations of similar classes in an UML Class Diagram?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Trying to implement a class diagram and I am not sure how should it done properly. Here is the problem:

> Miners can extract gold, silver and coal (the mines are homogeneous, always contains one type). In addition, there are some dangerous mines: e.g some might collapse or be radioactive.

How can I represent this on a class diagram? First, I thought it can be done with one `Mines` class. From that with generalization I candefine the collapsible and radioactive mines. But I can't decide how to deal with the different material types. Should that be classes too or attributes in the Mines class?

Comment: A subclass is typically used if the subclass has more attributes or methods that the parent class. From your description it is unclear why you want to subclass mines. Think about which other classes of objects you have in your example and what the relationships are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpler the better. Without specific behavior in the statement depending on the extracted substance it is enough to have only one class Mine, and the the list of possible substances being known an enumeration is enough. Because a mine produces only one substance the multiplicity is 1.

The statement doesn't say if the mine can both be radioactive and collapse or not.

Supposing a mine can both be radioactive and can collapse, you can use an attribute for each danger:

[image]

It is also possible to use a enumeration for the danger and the multiplicity `0..2` but it is also necessary to have a constraint saying each danger appears at most one time, so this is not a simple way.

Else if even less probable a mine can have at most one danger you can again use a enumeration with the multiplicity 1:

[image]

or with the multiplicity `0..1`:

[image]

Comment: How can it be done without the Substance enumeration? According to my task I have to check and count the gathered resources, so it would be great if they behave as a separate object and not as a value.

Comment: @Anonymous Why to have an enumeration is incompatible with checking and counting the gathered resources and why to have a class for is not ? Out of that I see you did not place all the statement in your question, if needed edit it

Comment: An enumeration is a data type, just like Integer. I recommend to define an attribute `substance : Substance` in class Mine and draw a dependency relationship (dashed arrow) from Mine to Substance. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48898810/5483079

Comment: I did not say that an enumeration is equivalent to an integer, I tried to explain that enumerations and integers are both data types. See section 10.2.3 of the UML specification.

Comment: Yes, the dependency is redundant. Drawing it may be helpful to stress the fact that the enumeration is used by the class.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl you are right when typed by an enumeration there is no association but an attribute must be used, I edited my diagrams to correct them

Comment: In the case of `0..2` Dangers, it is not necessary to constraint them to be different. In fact this is the default for Properties: {unique,unordered}. That means the values in the set of Dangers must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to model this is by defining the material in the mine as an enumeration. An enumeration is a data type, which you can use to define an attribute, as follows:

[image]

The dependency arrow from Mine to Material is redundant, because it is already implied by the fact that it is used as an attribute type, but in a more complex class diagram, I find it helpful to easily see which enumerations are used by which classes.

I did not use generalization for the various types of mines, because the subclasses would not have special features, so I go for the most simple solution.

I did not use generalization for the dangers, because a mine may be both collapsing and radioactive.

Comment: The UML allows to show attributes, even when they are not ends of an Association, in an association like notation. So there is no need to add a redundant Dependency. Just use a navigable Association notation. Unfortunately not many tools support this. However, it is perfectly legal to define an Association between a Class and an Enumeration. It doesn't add any semantics, but at least it allows to show the arrow. And in contrast to the dependency, it will disappear, when the attribute it deleted.

Comment: @AxelScheithauer, thanks for your valuable comment. I see the advantage of having an association instead of a dependency. Personally, I still prefer my solution. It gives a better visual distinction of relationships among business entities compared to relationships between attributes and their data types. Feel free to add your own answer to this question. I think it would have a lot of added value to see the various opinions as answers to this question.